OpenSearch not creating admin-cert after removing http on tls block
Version 2.16.0 and 2.17.0
I’ve been using OpenSearch with the security.tls.http.generate: true option enable, and everything its been working fine. However, when I remove that option to use TLS and self-generated certificates, the admin-cert secret is not being generated, others secrets (ca, transport-cert, admin-password) are being created successfully. As per the documentation on (opensearch-k8s-operator/docs/userguide/main.md at main · opensearch-project/opensearch-k8s-operator · GitHub) it should be enough by removing the http part and leave only security.tls.transport.generate and perNode.
I’m getting below errors.
1.- MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume “admin-cert” : secret “opensearch-admin-cert” not found.
2.- Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[admin-cert], unattached volumes=, failed to process volumes=: timed out waiting for the condition
This is the manifest file I'm using:
apiVersion: opensearch.opster.io/v1
kind: OpenSearchCluster
metadata:
  name: opensearch-latest
  namespace: opensearch                   
spec:
  bootstrap: {}
  confMgmt:
    smartScaler: false
  general:
    version: "2.17.0"
    httpPort: 9200
    vendor: opensearch
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:2.17.0      
    serviceName: opensearch-latest
    monitoring:
      enable: false
    drainDataNodes: true
    setVMMaxMapCount: true
  dashboards:
    enable: true
    version: "2.17.0"            
    replicas: 1
    resources:
      requests:
         memory: "512Mi"
         cpu: "200m"
      limits:
         memory: "512Mi"
         cpu: "200m"
  nodePools:
    - component: managers
      replicas: 3
      diskSize: "30Gi"
      persistence:
        pvc:
          storageClass: managed
          accessModes:
            - ReadWriteOnce
      nodeSelector: {}
      resources:
        requests:
          memory: "2Gi"
          cpu: "200m"
        limits:
          memory: "2Gi"
          cpu: "500m"
      roles:
        - "cluster_manager"
    - component: nodes
      replicas: 3
      diskSize: "100Gi"
      persistence:
        pvc:
          storageClass: managed
          accessModes:
            - ReadWriteOnce
      nodeSelector: {}
      resources:
        requests:
          memory: "2Gi"
          cpu: "500m"
        limits:
          memory: "2Gi"
          cpu: "1000m"
      roles:
        - data
        - ingest
  security:
    config: {}
      #adminCredentialsSecret:
      #name: admin-pwd
      #securityConfigSecret:
      #name: securityconfig
    tls:
      #http:
      #  generate: true
      transport:
        generate: true
          #perNode: true

